# ProgressDialog not closing

Tags: android, progressdialog

This is my code, seems like everything is good but when the app start doesn´t close the ProgressDialog, it´s cancelable but don´t dissapear and it´s showing since the app starts, and it´s not suposed to be like that

```js
 private void displayView(int position) {
  final int thePos=position;
  final ProgressDialog myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Procesando...", true);
  myProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               try {      
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                 MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                       
       
  // update the main content by replacing fragments
  Fragment fragment = null;
  switch (thePos) {
  /*case 0:
   fragment = new  HomeFragment();
   break;*/
  case 1:
   fragment = new  HomeFragment();
   break;
  case 2:
   fragment = new  CalendarioFragment();
   break;
  case 5:
   fragment = new  ContactoFragment();
   break;
  case 6:
   fragment = new  OnclickFragment();
   break;
  default:
   break;
  }

  if (fragment != null) {
   try{
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

   // update selected item and tit|le, then close the drawer
   mDrawerList.setItemChecked(thePos, true);
   mDrawerList.setSelection(thePos);
   setTitle(navMenuTitles[thePos]);
   mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
   }
   catch(Exception E)
   {
    Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
   }
  } 
  else {
   // error in creating fragment
   Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
  }
 }});
               }                
           
        catch (Throwable t) {
               // just end the background thread
               Log.i("Animation", "Thread  exception " + t);
           }
       }

       private void threadMsg(String msg) {

           if (!msg.equals(null) && !msg.equals("")) {
               Message msgObj = handler.obtainMessage();
               Bundle b = new Bundle();
               b.putString("message", msg);
               msgObj.setData(b);
               handler.sendMessage(msgObj);
           }
       }

       // Define the Handler that receives messages from the thread and update the progress
       private final Handler handler = new Handler() {

           public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                
               String aResponse = msg.getData().getString("message");

               if ((null != aResponse)) {
                   myProgressDialog.dismiss();
               }
           }
       }; 
   })
 .start(); } //After call start method thread called run Method
```

can anybody see the error? show me please

Comment: `when the app start doesn´t close the ProgressDialog,`. ??? When the app starts it should first display a ProgressDialog before you can close it. You forgot to tell when the dialog is supposed to close. Moreover you also did not tell where/when you display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a couple hours, i realized that the progress dialog i´ts wrong, i add it into the onItemClick and do the switch in a class, so there's the answer to add a ProgressDialog into a NavigationDrawer

```js
 private class SlideMenuClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
    long id) {
   final int thePos=position;
   final ProgressDialog myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Procesando...", true);
   myProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {      
                 Thread.sleep(2000);
                  MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
   // display view for selected nav drawer item
   displayView(thePos);
    myProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        }});
                }                
            
         catch (Throwable t) {
                // just end the background thread
                Log.i("Animation", "Thread  exception " + t);
            }
        }

        private void threadMsg(String msg) {

            if (!msg.equals(null) && !msg.equals("")) {
                Message msgObj = handler.obtainMessage();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("message", msg);
                msgObj.setData(b);
                handler.sendMessage(msgObj);
            }
        }

        // Define the Handler that receives messages from the thread and update the progress
        private final Handler handler = new Handler() {

            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                 
                String aResponse = msg.getData().getString("message");

                if ((null != aResponse)) {
                    myProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        }; 
    })
  .start(); }
  }
 

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
  if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
   return true;
  }
  // Handle action bar actions click
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id.action_settings:
   return true;
  default:
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
 }

 /* *
  * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
  */
 @Override
 public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
  boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
  menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
  
  CreaMenu();
  
  return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
 }

 /**
  * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
  * */
 
 private void displayView(int position) {
  final int thePos=position;
  
                       
       
  // update the main content by replacing fragments
  Fragment fragment = null;
  switch (thePos) {
  /*case 0:
   fragment = new  HomeFragment();
   break;*/
  case 1:
   fragment = new  HomeFragment();
   break;
  case 2:
   fragment = new  CalendarioFragment();
   break;
  case 5:
   fragment = new  ContactoFragment();
   break;
  case 6:
   fragment = new  OnclickFragment();
   break;
  default:
   break;
  }

  if (fragment != null) {
   try{
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

   // update selected item and tit|le, then close the drawer
   mDrawerList.setItemChecked(thePos, true);
   mDrawerList.setSelection(thePos);
   setTitle(navMenuTitles[thePos]);
   mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
   }
   catch(Exception E)
   {
    Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
   }
  } 
  else {
   // error in creating fragment
   Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
  }
 }
  //After call start method thread called run Method
```